# disable the cursor pointer on lightning-output-field in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

i am trying to disable cursor on `lightning-output-field` phone field but no luck. my styles are not rendering in UI.
is it because am i applying styles for child elements?

**lwc.html**

```
<template> 
  <lightning-card icon-name="standard:account" title="Reporter"  class="slds-card_boundary">
    
    <lightning-record-edit-form density="comfy" record-id={reporterrecid} mode={recordformmode} class="disableopflds"  object-api-name="Associate__c" >
         <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <div class="disableopflds slds-grid slds-wrap" if:true={iseditbtnshowed}>
            <div class="disableopflds slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-p-around_small">
             <lightning-output-field class="disableopflds slds-border_bottom" field-name="Phone__c"></lightning-output-field>
           </div>
       </div>
   </lightning-record-edit-form>
 <lightning-card
<template>
```

i used below styles none of them is not working, but if i give same style via browser inspect dev console it's working.
in below screen i gave  `pointer-events: none;` manually in browser then it works.

**lwc.css**

```
.disableopflds{
    pointer-events: none;
    color: black;
}

.disableopflds.a{
    pointer-events: none;
    color: black;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since LWC is enforcing the shadow DOM style scoping, we can't currently style other Elements outside your shadow tree.

so we have multiple workarounds to apply custom styles for LWC components(out side shadow tree)

**Approach 1:**

if you put LWC component inside an Aura component and add the CSS targeting inner elements & styles in the css file of that aura components so that styles 'll apply for LWC elememts since Aura components do not enforce strict CSS encapsulation.

**Approach 2:**

put the CSS styles what ever you wanted to apply to the inner shadow DOM of LWC Base Components and upload as a static resource. Then we use the loadStyle method of `lightning/platformResourceLoader` module to load that css. The styles loaded this way do apply to the inner elements within LWC base components. [check out here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library)

**Approach 3:**

i ended up with below workaround for now.

```
renderedCallback() {
    if (this.hasRendered) return;
    this.hasRendered = true;

    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerText = `c-m-y_-lwc-coponent lightning-output-field a{ //"c-m-y_-lwc-component" is your component name
    pointer-events: none; 
    color: black;
  }`;
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-output-field').appendChild(style);
}
```

[image]

be careful while using above approaches because neither one is ideal. so we are looking forward to a better solution provided by Salesforce via [::part and ::theme](https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use below styles:

```
.disableopflds {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

As my suggest, can you provide this class name in html. But attached screenshot not having like this. Thanks.

```
<div class="disableopflds slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-p-around_small">
   <lightning-output-field class="disableopflds slds-border_bottom" field-name="Phone__c">
   </lightning-output-field>
</div>
```

Comment: my styles are not rendered , for adding here with different name but in my files both are same, any way i updated Question still styles are not rendering

Answer (score -1):

sdandamud1,

As a quick test, try the following. This should keep the cursor from appearing on hover.

```
<lightning-output-field class="disableopflds slds-border_bottom" field-name="Phone__c" style="cursor: none;"></lightning-output-field>
```

Comment: i am doing down voting, because we can't apply styles directly to lightning base components

Comment: sdandamud1, I'm my last comment, I said "AS A QUICK TEST". This is simply to determine whether this provides the results you're looking for.  If so, remove the inline-style then, add it to the correct class in your css, ie .disableopflds {cursor: none;}

Comment: i already did, but my styles are not rendering to browser that's  actual problem. why my styles are not render to UI